# programmatically created button click to open a tableview or popup

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have created a button programmatically in a `UITableViewCell` and I want it to open a new table view or popup when clicked. Please give me some tutorial or hint. Below is my code:

```
UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,360,25);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dropDownClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)dropDownClick
{
    //Here I know there should be some code but I am not getting what it should be since I am new to iPad/iPhone development
}
```

Comment: Your answers are going to vary wildly if you don't know exactly what you'd like to show. Might I suggest the [iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to show a popup when tapping the button, you can use `UIAlertVIew`

```
- (IBAction)dropDownClick {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of popup" 
                                                    message:@"Did this popup show?" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample to do it

```
//DISEGNO DELLE CELLE
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier;

CellIdentifier = @"CellStorico";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect tRect1 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 3.0f, 768.0f, 40.0f);
    id title1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:tRect3];
    [title1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [title1 setTag:3];

    [cell addSubview:title1];
    [title1 release];

}




if ([[[Storico objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"Selezionato"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];        
} else {
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}   



return cell;
}
```

Click Management

```
-(void)ClickCheck:(id)sender{

//Ex. Load a New View
FrmScadenzeGenerali *SchermataScadenzeGenerali=[[FrmScadenzeGenerali alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrmScadenzeGenerali" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:SchermataScadenzeGenerali animated:YES];
[SchermataScadenzeGenerali release];


//Ex. PopUp a View
[self.view insertSubview:[TabTestata view] atIndex:0];

//Show a Message
UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione!" message:@"Error Text Message To Show!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [Alert show];
    [Alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a `UINavigationController` with your `UITableView`.

If so, you can do try this to make it open a new table view:

- Make a new class which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Make sure the checkbox named "With XIB for user interface" is checked. Give it a name, i.e. "MyTableViewController".
- Open the implementation file (the one ending in .m) of your class where you have your `dropDownClick` method, and import your new class with `#import "MyTableViewController.h"`. Do this at the top of your class (.m file).
- Edit your `dropDownClick` method to the following lines:

---

```
-(IBAction)dropDownClick
{
    MyTableViewController *vc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController"]; // Loads a .xib file called "MyTableViewController.xib"
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; // This is where the swapping happens.
    [vc release]; // Remember to do this if your app does not use ARC.
}
```

You could also do this without using a .xib, but then it would be a bit different.